# How do you check if you're on a proxy server?

Tags: proxy, aws

How do you check if you're on a proxy server? I noticed I can't install anything on my staging server, and I remembered that there was some weird configuration that was done to keep it safe from outsiders, so I am thinking I am behind a proxy. So how do you check that, and how do you know if the proxy is on Amazon and get additional information I may need to configure Composer to work.

Comment: By using `traceroute` or installing and using `tracepath`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `traceroute` to see all of the hops from your computer to a particular server.

Install with:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install traceroute
```

Then open a terminal and run:

```
traceroute 1.1.1.1
```

This will send a packet to the IP address `1.1.1.1` (Cloudflare's Privacy DNS)

The output will list the path of this packet by listing information about every IP address, in order, starting with your computer's local IP address and ending with `1.1.1.1`.

The first few hops will be on your local network. The next few hops should be your ISP.  If there are no hops in between your ISP and `1.1.1.1`, then this traffic did not go through a proxy.

If you don't recognize an IP address, you can usually look up ownership and registration information.  There are several web-based "whois" IP lookup services online, or you can do it yourself by installing `whois` and using the `whois` command as follows

```
whois 1.1.1.1
```